# Illustrator's background and artboard became transparent

Tags: adobe-illustrator, background, artboard

[image: image showing problem]

Illustrator has a less known feature to hide artboard and background. I accidentally activated this with some keyboard shortcut. How do I go back to the normal view?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You turned on the "Transparent Grid". You can go to *View* → *Hide Transparency Grid* or hit <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

Comment: instead of a transparent view in my case everything beneath my content is white only!? I don't have any borders for my Artboards...

Answer (score 0):

If everything goes white and you want to see the defined artboards, hit <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.

Comment: Dartboards?  Do you mean artboards perhaps?

Comment: You mean Darthboards?

Comment: I edited this so if somebody could clean up these comments?

Comment: @Culme You mean Darth's bored?